# Turning on facebook messenger camera through Dialogflow chatbot

Tags: facebook, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I created a chatbot on Dialogflow which informs the user about the names of the members of my (extended) family and about where they are the living. I have created a small database with MySQL which has these data stored and I fetch them with a PHP script whenever this is appropriate depending on the interaction of the user with the chatbot.

I have integrated this chatbot to Facebook Messenger. My question is the following:

**Can I directly trigger the Facebook messenger camera to be turned on through Dialogflow (and without using any other front-end camera)?**

The reason I want to turn on the camera is to allow the user to take a photo of himself/herself and then I will process the photo with some computer vision libraries to infer if this person at the photo is a family member of mine. Obviously, I can simply create another basic front-end where I will turn on a camera whenever e.g. an intent called 'Camera' is triggered but I was wondering if can do this directly on facebook messenger.

The json response that I am receiving at my back-end from Dialogflow contains only the following UI capabilities:

```
    "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
            {
                "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
            },
            {
                "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
                "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
                "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
            }
        ]
    }
```

therefore my first impression is that turning on a camera directly through Dialoglfow (and Facebook Messenger) is not possible.

**Am I right?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're right... but probably not for the reasons you think.

First, you're not going to be able to turn on the Facebook Messenger camera because you're not using Facebook Messenger. You're using the Google Assistant. Right now, the Google Assistant doesn't define a way to send an image to the Action you're interacting with. (It does work with Google Lens, but at this point, there is no way to get that to you.)

Second, you wouldn't actually "turn on" the camera. If the user sends you an image through the Messenger camera, you can process this by looking at the `originalRequest` field in the JSON you get on your fulfillment which should contain the [message from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messages) which contains the image.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Prisoner. To be honest, I suspected that it was not exactly for the reasons I stated above but I just wanted to add some code so that my post complies with the (unwritten) rules of StackOverflow. Therefore, if I understand right your first point, I cannot directly open the camera through Dialogflow without the user pressing at least one button to turn it on. Regarding your second point, I agree and had this in my mind.

Comment: Dialogflow is not in control of what the client chat/conversation system does. So it has nothing to do with "turning on" the camera at all. The first point has more to do that the Google Assistant has no camera interface for Actions.